# How to select greater number and lower number using LINQ To SQL in C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, c#-4.0

I have a `TABLE` in SQL Database there is a columns in 
`TABLE ID,Subject,Body,Status,TimeDate` in the 400 row data and each i have take a Id as a P_Key and Identity Specification is Yes.

Here is `Id = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 etc..`

I want to select greater Id from table based on saved old id like i have saved ID 12 in  im getting same id like this with Linq Query below:

```
      public static int CheckId()
      {
          DataClassesDataContext con = new DataClassesDataContext(Globals.con);
            var q = from v in con.TABLE
                    where v.Id== 12 & v.Status == Active
                    select v.Id;
            foreach (var val in q)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(val);
            }
            return 0;
      }
```

the i can return a greater id then 12. and there is also one issue. if there is greater `ID` is Missing from DB example Id 13 is missing then i will get Id 14 in that case. please let me know how can i get id like this i want from db using linq query.

Comment: FYI, you can't have `<` or `>` in a post unless they are quoted.

Comment: @DeveloperKinks Can you clarify - Do you want the next Id value after the given Id? If you provide 12, it should return 13. However if 13 is missing should it return null or should it return 14?

Comment: yes if 13 is missing should be return 14. then

Comment: Yeah, only it was ok before your edit because I added the quotes!

Comment: I try to example below not working give some issue

Answer (score 1):

Use `Min`

```
return con.<TABLE>
       .Where(v=>v.ID > 12)
       .Select(v=>v.ID)
       .DefaultIfEmpty()
       .Min();
```

Comment: I not getting where exactly i have to use Min in query can you please complete my query by adding you suggestion. so that will be easy understating use of Min

Comment: have a bug Could not format node 'OptionalValue' for execution as SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample for you

```
    List<Int32> test = new List<Int32>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,13,15,16};
    var min = test.Where(x=>x>12).Min();
```

Gives result 13 only, even when 14 is the first bigger

In Your case

```
//get a table object
Table table = new Table() //if you want whole row.

table = con.Table.Where(x=>x.id>12).MIN();
```

Comment: yes it is working but how should i can get id like this from database based on Id and Status. if you have couple of mint to help me please show me how can i use it in LIQ Query I'm not very expert in it.

Comment: like this   DataContext con = new DataContext(Global.con);
            Table Table = new Table();
            Table = con.Emails.Where(x => x.Id > 1).Min();
            return Table;

Comment: Rex can you plz explain it. the Table which is use of linq or Table of using System.Web.UI.WebControls; we sever is develop as a desktop Application please let me know how tho i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you already have:

```
DataClassesDataContext con = new DataClassesDataContext(Globals.con);

var q = from v in con.TABLE
        where v.Id > 12 & v.Status == Active
        orderby v.Id
        select v.Id;

return q.Take(1); // to return the whole row
// or    
return q.Take(1).Id; // to return only the Id
```

This would return the first row meeting the criterias (id > 12, status = active). Add error handling code as needed.